# Передача массива с Php в Js

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, массивы, reactjs

Помогите пожалуйста: имеется массив в реакте (скрин приложил)

```
var todos = [{
    task: 'uebat dimasu',
    isCompleted: false
}, {
    task: 'SAAAASAI',
    isCompleted: true
}];
```

[image: Код реакта]

Стоит задача получить массив из БД и с помощью php передать массив в Js в таком виде как на скрине. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать?

Comment: пожалуйста, не выкладывайте код с помощью снимков экрана, ну что мешает сделать Ctrl+C и Ctrl+V для подходящего фрагмента

Comment: Массив в JS:

 var todos = [{
     task: 'uebat dimasu',
     isCompleted: false
 }, {
     task: 'SAAAASAI',
     isCompleted: true
 }];

Comment: Что мешает найти ответ с помощью поисковика. Тема заезжена....

Comment: Вы каким образом получаете данные из бд

Answer (score 0):

PHP код для выборки из БД (`data/getToDo.php`).

```
echo json_encode(DataBase::fetchAll("SELECT * FROM todo"));
```

Получение данных в JS

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'data/getToDo.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (toDoList) {
        startTodoProccess(todoList);
    }
});
```

В функции `startTodoProccess(todoList)` делаете что хотите с этими данными. А уже формат массива получаемого в результате AJAX запроса зависит от типа запроса к БД. Да и вообще, вы ведь можете потом на уровне PHP результат отформатировать как угодно.